# Fusionar repositorios sin perder comits ni fechas de edicion

Tags: git, github, repositorio

Hola me gustaria meter dentro de un repositorio A todo lo que hay en un repositorio B, un repositorio C y un repositorio D

Seria algo asi:

Contenido repositorio a antes de fusionar tendria toda la informacion que ya hay en el y despues de fusionar tendria toda su informacion + toda la de los demas repositorios todo esto sin perder ningun commit ni ninguna fecha de los commit

Estoy usando github para almacenar los repositorios

Redicion:
basicamente tengo 4 repositorios y quiero fusionar todo en 1 repositorio principal, la rama en la que quiero tener todo es la main y el arbol de directorio seria algo asi:
`repoprincipal/contenido repoprincipal/repoB repoprincipal/repoC repoprincipal/repoD`

y que se vea todo en un mismo repositorio manteniendo todos los commits y las fechas

Comment: Para poder responder apropiadamente, me podrías decir que te gustaría ver en el árbol de trabajo cuando hagas checkout de `main`? O si te lo imaginas funcionando con varias ramas, pues explicar con detalle en la pregunta.

Comment: basicamente tengo 4 repositorios y quiero fusionar todo en 1 repositorio principal, la rama en la que quiero tener todo es la main y el arbol de directorio seria algo asi: 
`
repoprincipal/contenido
repoprincipal/repoB
repoprincipal/repoC
repoprincipal/repoD` 
y que se vea todo en un mismo repositorio manteniendo todos los commits y las fechas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que creamos 1 repositorio nuevo, localmente

```
git init todo-junto
cd todo-junto
```

En este repositorio, agregamos los otros repositorios como *remotos*

```
git remote add proyectoX url-proyecto-X
git remote add proyectoY url-proyecto-Y
.
.
.
```

Al tener los otros repos como remotos, creemos una rama *local* para cada `main/master` de esos remotos, para poder entonces colocar los archivos de cada proyecto en un *subdirectorio*  de la rama final.

```
git fetch --all # ver todo lo que hay en los remotos
git checkout -b ramaX proyectoX/main
mkdir directorioX
git mv . directorioX
git commit -m "proyectoX: moviendo todo a directorioX"
git checkout -b ramaY proyectoY/master
mkdir directorioY
git mv . directorioY
git commit -m "proyectoY: moviendo todo a directorioY"
.
.
.
```

Cuando ya tengamos hecho todo esto en todos los proyectos, cada uno en su rama local, podemos proceder a mezclar las historias y contenidos... tomamos una de las ramas como la base de nuestra rama `main` y mezclamos las otras:

```
git checkout -b main ramaX
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories ramaY -m "mezclando proyectoY"
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories ramaZ -m "mezclando proyectoZ"
```

De esta forma ya fusionamos todas las historias y cada proyecto queda en su propio directorio de nuestra rama `main`.... en este punto podemos empujar a donde creamos conveniente.

Comment: Pero en el caso de que el primer repositorio no este vacio como lo haria? Basicamente porque repositorio principal donde se va a guardar el proyectoX y el proyectoY tiene contenido que no quiero perder y tampoco puedo meter todo ese contenido en otro repositorio
Osea esta el repositorioA que tiene contenidoA y donde quiero fusionar con repositorioX y repositorioY en una carpeta para contenidoX y otra para contenidoY

Comment: El resultado final lo podrías empujar a una rama de uno de los remotos ya existentes (por eso dije al final **en este punto podemos empujar _a donde creamos conveniente_**)

Comment: Como lo empujo a otro repositorio los merge finales?

Comment: `git push algun-remoto main:alguna-rama-remota`.